# Interpreting Entropy (Comprehension Question)

Tags: probability, information-theory, entropy

> Consider a fair coin toss X .  There are two outcomes, each with
>   probability 1/2.  The entropy of this random variable is
>
> $H ( X ) = − \Big(\frac{1}{2} \log_2\big(\frac{1}{2}\big) + \frac{1}{2}\log_2\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)\Big)= 1$

I'm a bit confused on how to interpret $1$
as the value of the entropy.. What can I deduce from that?

I guess the question is how can I interpret these values say if the values was lower $0.25$ or something

Comment: _"... 1  as the value of the entropy_ " Not 1, but 1 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entropy of a finite probability distribution ${\bf p}=(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$ is a measure for the uncertainty about the outcome of the corresponding experiment. If $p_1=0.97$ and $p_2=0.03$ this uncertainty is small, but if $p_1=p_2={1\over2}$ this uncertainty is large. Thinking about the problem in depth shows that the quantity
$$H({\bf p}):=\sum_{k=1}^n p_k\log_2{1\over p_k}\tag{1}$$
has the properties that one would wish for such a measure, e.g. when more complicated situations are at stake. (I'm sure this is explained in your textbook.) Of course we need a "unit of uncertainty". This unit is called $1$ **bit** and is the uncertainty involved in the most simple experiment: the throw of a fair coin. By taking the $\log$ to base $2$ in $(1)$ it is assured that $H\bigl({1\over2},{1\over2}\bigr)=1$.